# linstalling libc6:amd64 would break locales, and deconfiguration is not permitted

Tags: debian, libc

I couldn't install libc6_2.29-9_amd64 on my debian machine 
when i type this command:

```
 sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.29-9_amd64.deb
```

I get this message back:

```
dpkg: regarding libc6_2.29-9_amd64.deb containing libc6:amd64:
libc6:amd64 breaks locales (<< 2.29)   locales (version
2.24-11+deb9u4) is present and installed.
 dpkg: error processing archive libc6_2.29-9_amd64.deb (--install):  installing libc6:amd64 would break locales, and  deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help) Errors were encountered while processing:  libc6_2.29-9_amd64.deb
```

Am stuck at this point. knowing that I want to update it to at least libc6_2.29

Comment: Did you solve your problem?